# NSFetchRequest with SwiftUI View & Swift Class - "executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity."

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I am new to swift/iOS programming and tried to fix the issue with the other threads on StackOverflow, however, I couldn't fix it. I have a simple swift app which provides the following functionalities:

- Fetching data from a API
- Storing that data in core data framework
- Searching/Fetching this Data
- Enables the user to save & display transactions in core data in a swiftui view

I am getting the following error as I am trying to implement a FetchRequest on the stored data (api data as well as transactions from the view): "executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity."

However, both functions alone do work:

- If I am calling the "getDataFromCoreData()" function from my swiftui view, the response is the api data from core data
- If I am calling the FilteredList, the stored transactions are displayed in a List
- If I open the transaction list & call the "getDataFromCoreData()" function the error gets thrown

What am I doing wrong here?

PersistentManager.swift

```
private(set) static var shared = PersistentStore()

    static var preview: PersistentStore = {
        let result = PersistentStore()
        let viewContext = result.persistentContainer.viewContext
        for index in 0..<10 {
            let newItem = Transaction(context: viewContext)
            newItem.id = UUID()
        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            (...)
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

// this makes sure we're the only one who can create one of these
private init() { }
    
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    (...)
    return container
}()

var context: NSManagedObjectContext { persistentContainer.viewContext }

func saveContext () {
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("Unresolved error saving context: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

}

ApiClass.swift - storing data in core data is working fine, as well as the following function:

```
func getDataFromCoreData() {
    let context = PersistentStore.shared.context
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Data>(entityName: "Data")
    do {
        let data = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for d in data {

          print(d.name)

        }
      } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      }
}
```

ContentView.swift / FiltertedList - working fine, but when I am calling the above function (getDataFromCoreData()) from the swiftui view, the list with transaction gets displayed, but the following error gets thrown: executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.

```
struct FilteredList: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context

@Binding var searchText: String

var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Transaction>
var transactionItems: FetchedResults<Transaction> {
    fetchRequest.wrappedValue
}

init(_ searchText: Binding<String>) {
    self._searchText = searchText

    let predicate = searchText.wrappedValue.isEmpty ? NSPredicate(value: true) : NSPredicate(format: "companyName CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText.wrappedValue)

    self.fetchRequest = FetchRequest(entity: Transaction.entity(),
                                     sortDescriptors: [ NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Transaction.companyName, ascending: true) ],
                                     predicate: predicate,
                                     animation: .default)
}
```

Transaction.class (manual)

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Transaction)
public class Transaction: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var symbol: String
    @NSManaged public var companyName: String
    @NSManaged public var currency: String
    @NSManaged public var purchaseDate: Date
    @NSManaged public var purchasePrice: Double
    @NSManaged public var quantity: Int16
}
```

Comment: Do you use manual class for Transaction entity? If yes, can you share that implementation

Comment: @davidev yes! I did edit the class to my post above.

Comment: But what is `getDataFromCoreData` supposed to do? Do you also have an entity "Data"?

Comment: Yes @JoakimDanielson - its a different entity/class which stores data from the api. I have two entities: Transactions (user-entered and stored) and "Data" (api-requested and stored)

Comment: Ok but don't name your entity (or any custom type) the same as built-in types like Data in this instance since it might lead to unexpected errors and also makes the code confusing to read. Start with using a new name and see if it helps.